# distinct condition in case statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL that returns a cnt1 and cnt2 for each Event_ID, while testing a condition for column "POSA"

this returns the following as desired:

Event_ID | CNT1 | CNT2

I would like to add another condition to each CASE statement that tests if another column "S" in the same table is distinct.  Below is the code snippet:

```
SELECT Event_ID, 
 sum  
 (CASE WHEN POSA IN ('SX', 'DX')  THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
 END) 
 AS cnt1,
sum 
(CASE  
    WHEN POSA IN ('SP', 'DP')  THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
 END) AS cnt2


FROM Station_Processed_Info GROUP BY EVENT_ID;
```

Comment: Some example data would help make this clearer.

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple values for S within a single EVENT_ID group?  Also, when looking for duplicate values of S do you just want to look within the current EVENT_ID group, or through the whole table?

Comment: John, it is possible to have multiple values for S within the Event_ID group, but the condition is that each S should be distinct, and regarding the second part, the "distinctness" should be only within the same Event_ID group.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Event_ID,   
SUM(CASE 
   WHEN POSA IN ('SX', 'DX')  THEN 1
   WHEN DISTINCT("S") THEN something 
    ELSE 0   END)   AS cnt1, 
SUM (CASE  
    WHEN POSA IN ('SP', 'DP')  THEN 1
    WHEN DISTINCT("S") THEN something 
    ELSE 0   END) AS cnt2    
FROM Station_Processed_Info GROUP BY EVENT_ID;
```

Comment: You can add multiple WHEN clauses to a CASE statement.